# function for json parsing returns decode error

Tags: json, swift

I am new to Swift and currently I am learning about JSON parsing. I found some example json file and i wanted to decode into object, but I am getting error which I cant find in my code.

JSON FILE

```
{
"apiVersion": "v1",
"context": "success",
"httpCode": 200,
"method": "GET",
"baseUrl": "http://expecting.devtvornica.org",
"uri": "api/v1/baby-names/get?country=hr",
"queryParameters": {
    "country": "hr",
    "order_by": "name",
    "sort_order": "ASC"
},
"data": {
    "favorites": [
        {
            "id": 962,
            "name": "Adam",
            "country": "hr",
            "gender": "male",
            "is_favorite": false
        },
        {
            "id": 930,
            "name": "Adrian",
            "country": "hr",
            "gender": "male",
            "is_favorite": false
        },
        {
            "id": 974,
            "name": "BAdriano",
            "country": "hr",
            "gender": "male",
            "is_favorite": true
        },
        {
            "id": 959,
            "name": "CAlen",
            "country": "hr",
            "gender": "male",
            "is_favorite": false
        },
        {
            "id": 985,
            "name": "CAna",
            "country": "hr",
            "gender": "female",
            "is_favorite": true
        },
    ]
}
}
```

RESPONSE CLASS

```
import Foundation

public class Response <T: Codable>: Codable{

public let apiVersion: String?
public let context: String?
public let httpCode: Int?
public let method: String?
public let baseUrl: String?
public let uri: String?
public let message: String?
public let queryParameters: [QueryParameters]?
public let data:T?

public init(data: T, apiVersion: String, context: String, httpCode: Int, method: String, baseUrl: String, uri: String, message: String, queryParameters: [QueryParameters]){
    
    self.apiVersion = apiVersion
    self.context = context
    self.httpCode = httpCode
    self.method = method
    self.baseUrl = baseUrl
    self.uri = uri
    self.message = message
    self.queryParameters = queryParameters
    self.data = data
}
}
```

STRUCT FILES

```
import Foundation

public struct BabyFavorite: Codable {

public let favorites: [BabyName]

}





import Foundation

public struct BabyName: Codable {

public let id: Int
public let name: String
public let country: String
public let gender: String
public let isFavorite: Bool
}
```

VIEWCONTROLLER

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    getBabyNames()
}
}

extension ViewController {
private func getBabyNames(){
    if let localData = self.readLocalField(forName: "get_baby_names_country_success"),
       let responseData: Response <BabyFavorite> = parse(jsonData: localData),
       let data = responseData.data {
        handleBabyNames(data: data)
    }
}

private func handleBabyNames(data: BabyFavorite){
    data.favorites.forEach { (babyname) in
        
        print(babyname)
    }
}
}

extension ViewController {
static let jsonDecoder: JSONDecoder = {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    return decoder
}()

private func readLocalField(forName name: String) -> Data? {
    do {
        if let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "json"),
           let jsonData = try String(contentsOfFile: bundlePath).data(using: .utf8){
            return jsonData
        }
    }catch{
        print(error)
    }
    
    return nil
    
}

private func parse<T: Codable>(jsonData: Data) -> T?{
    let object: T?
    do {
        object = try ViewController.jsonDecoder.decode(T.self, from: jsonData)
    } catch {
        print("decode error")
        object = nil
    }
    return object
}
}
```

My parse function is always catching error.
I found by breakpoint that line

```
let data = responseData.data {
    handleBabyNames(data: data)
```

doesnt execute, but I dont know how to actually fix this.

Comment: queryParameters Is not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

queryParameters is a object and u are decoding it as array

```
public let queryParameters: QueryParameters?
```